# La maldición de la palabra "loco": ¿cuál es su etimología?

Tags: etimología, adjetivos

Me hallaba buscando información acerca de cuán antigua es la expresión *loco de atar* (cosa que ya preguntaré más adelante), cuando me encuentro la siguiente perla de humor en el diccionario del señor Covarrubias, escrito allá por 1611 (énfasis mío):

> LOCO, el hombre que ha perdido su juyzio, [...]. **La etimología deste vocablo tornara loco a qualquier hombre cuerdo**, porque no se halla cosa que hincha su vacio.

Vamos, que si estudias la etimología de la palabra *loco* te volverás loco. Se ve que el pobre hombre pasó un mal rato tratando de buscar el origen de la palabra, porque postula las siguientes hipótesis, sin llegar a sacar nada en claro:

- Que venga de *locus, loci* 'lugar', dado que el loco ha dejado un lugar vacío donde debería estar su seso.
- Que venga de *Luco*, una población en el País Vasco, por una leyenda sobre unos demonios establecidos en bosques que no debían ser violados, so pena de quedar locos y agitados de las furias.
- Que venga de *lucus à luce per contrarium sensum*, por haberse ofuscado y entenebrecido el entendimiento. El *Autoridades* en 1734 dice que esta sería la opción más verosímil.
- Que venga de *loquendo*, porque los tales suelen con la sequedad del cerebro hablar mucho, y dar muchas voces.

En el mismo año, el señor Rosal publicó su diccionario etimológico en el que dice que podría parecer que viene de *loco motus* 'movido de su lugar', pero que no, que viene del verbo griego *halisco*, que significa "ser cogido, o tomado, o impedido", de donde sale el pretérito *heloca* y el participio *helocós* 'impedido, tomado, falto', y de ahí *loco* perdiendo la primera sílaba.

Curiosamente, la etimología tentativa que da hoy día el DLE [no es ninguna de estas](https://dle.rae.es/loco):

> Quizá del árabe hispánico **láwqa*, y este del árabe clásico *lawqā*', femenino de *alwaq* 'estúpido'; cf. port. *louco*.

Así pues, y para volvernos ya locos del todo: ¿qué otras etimologías se han planteado a lo largo del tiempo para la voz *loco*? ¿Cuál sería la más aceptada a día de hoy?

Answer (score 3):

Según [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?loco), el *Diccionario Crítico* de Juan Corominas menciona hasta **tres** posibles orígenes adicionales:

- Del italiano *[allocco](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000339.jpg)*, que significa *búho* (en concreto de la especie *[Strix aluco](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strix_aluco)*) y también, en sentido figurado, *estúpido*.
- Del personaje mitológico griego *Glaucos*, que se volvió loco.
- Del adjetivo [llueca](https://dle.rae.es/llueca)/[clueca](https://dle.rae.es/clueco), que se refiere a aves que están empollando sus huevos. Este adjetivo parece a su vez estar relacionado con el latín *locus* (lugar).

También según [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?loco), Corominas parece no estar convencido con ninguno de los posibles orígenes.

Comment: He revisado el diccionario de Corominas en sí, y todo lo expresado es correcto.

Answer (score 0):

En el Tarot Egipcio que data de 2600 antes de Cristo, existe una carta que se llama "El Loco", y que corresponde al Arcano número 22.

El loco significa "*el que vaga*", *"el que camina buscando un rumbo"*, por lo general, "El loco" carga con algo en su hombro y va acompañado por un perro.

Si se ven las similitudes numéricas con el tarot, el significado es el que busca una verdad y el que comienza un camino, aunque no sepa muy bien éste dónde puede llevarle. Algún tipo de ente superior lo guía y todo le sale bien, a pesar de la desaprobación de la gente.

En ese sentido, en la búsqueda hay algo muy similar al despertar espiritual, todos los genios fueron llamados locos, en el Tarot de Marsella que es posterior también está la misma carta con el mismo número.